# ¿Cómo declarar tipos enum en java?

Tags: java, enum

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual tengo distintas clases y estas clases distintos enumerados.

Ejemplo:

```
public enum Distancia{
    Corta (250),
    intermedia (275),
    larga (300);
    
    private final int distancia;
    
    Distancia (int distancia){
        this.distancia= distancia;
    }
    
    public int getVelociadad(){
        return this.distancia;
    }
}
```

Es la distancia que va a tener un objeto de tipo Circuito.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Cómo es más recomendable declararlo, en una clase aparte o en la clase circuito? Cumpliendo siempre los requisitos de encapsulación.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, pero siguiendo la lógica un circuito puede tener cierta distancia y una distancia no puede tener circuito, saludos.

Comment: El circuito solo puede tener esas tres distancias (para así obligarnos a utilizar el tipo enum) mi pregunta es: ¿Sí es más eficiente y hay mayor encapsulamiento si declaro el tipo enum distancia en una clase llamada distancia? o simplemente lo dejo dentro de la clase circuito

Comment: Ojo: ¿Sí es más eficiente y hay mayor encapsulamiento si declaro el tipo enum distancia en una clase llamada distancia? o simplemente lo dejo dentro de la clase circuito..... No es que sea más eficiente si no que es por mantenibilidad y limpieza de código si te apegas a lo que es la POO.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias Omar